# N-Tuples or N-functions in category theory

Tags: functions, category-theory

When I'm writing out categories of my Haskell programs, I often get stuck whilst trying to describe morphisms that involve functions that involve more than one argument, such as 2-tuple construction.

For instance, I may have a function ${\lambda a.\lambda b.\left<a,b\right> }$. I have an object ${A}$, and I apply the function as a morphism, returning (essentially) ${\lambda b.\left<a \in A, b\right>}$, which in Haskell, is a type, and therefore an object. The problem is, how can I then use that as a morphism? Is there another representation for morphisms in this pattern?

My question is, how can I describe morphisms which require two arguments, such as 2-tuples, in a category?

Comment: Could you give an example of where you get stuck?

Comment: @Calle Added, I hope it helps.

Comment: So you have f : a -> b -> (a,b) and then apply f (x:a)?

Comment: That's pretty much it.

Comment: You can either use products (which is the usual way) or exponential objects (which corresponds to curried functions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are asking, but your function $λa. λb. (a, b)$ is an element of type $a → (b → a × b)$, or more conventionally $((a × b)^b)^a$. If you apply it to a specific $a ∈ A$, you get an element of type $b → a × b$, which *is* a function from $b$ to $a × b$.

In categorical language, this is the setting of a *cartesian closed category*, which are characterized by having finite products, and a functor $[-, -] : \mathscr C^\mathrm{op} × \mathscr C → \mathscr C$ such that $\hom(A × B, C) ≅ \hom(A, [B, C])$ holds naturally in $A$, $B$ and $C$. In the category of sets, which is cartesian closed, $[A, B]$ is of course $B^A$, the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$, and in Haskell, $[a, b] = (a → b)$.
The bijection $\hom(A × B, C) ≅ \hom(A, [B, C])$ (currying) is a very strong condition, and it enables us to interpret $[A, B]$ as an *object of morphisms* from $A$ to $B$ even in general cartesian closed categories. Note for example that we have $\hom(A, B) ≅ \hom(1 × A, B) ≅ \hom(1, [A, B])$, where $1$ is the terminal object of $\mathscr C$, so morphisms from $A$ to $B$ are in bijection with morphisms from $1$ to $[A, B]$, so $[A, B]$ itself "knows" what $\hom(A, B)$ is.
More generally, you can do this in any monoidally closed category.

In fact, the notion of a morphism of multiple arguments makes sense in any [monoidal category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) $(\mathscr C, ⊗, I)$. You can call a morphism $A ⊗ B → C$ a "morphism with two arguments", and you can "partially apply" these too in a sense, but you loose "objects of morphisms" ie. what corresponds to Haskell's function types, and with it the evaluation morphism $\mathrm{ev} : [A, B] ⊗ A → B$, you have in monoidally closed categories, and finally the ability to convert functions of multiple arguments into functions of a single argument.